# ASP.NET MVC: customized design per domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm thinking about ASP.NET MVC 2 project which should display the same Domain Model(with different data) in different mark-up or page design(selected by url domain).

I'm not sure which one ot these to use :

1. set of views per unique domain + one default?
2. use areas?
3. any other idea?

How would you do that?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have finally came out with my own solution. Features:

- .NET 4 MVC 2
- frameworks,libraries: NCommon, EF4, MVCContrib, AntiXSS
- loading configuration(modules) per domain
- languages, localization, themes

There is a lot of things to do, but i can share my code to improve it. Send me an email to skorunka@genitor.cz

Comment: Are you talking about completely different mark-up, or could this be achieved using a combination of different style-sheets and/or master pages?

Comment: In fact, there may be parts with different mark-up. So not only views but even partial views, master pages, can be different. Only the model is same for everything.

Comment: To clarify.. Will there be several or more sites distinguished by domain name that will be using the same Domain Model (Code base) with the only difference being how the front ends look?

Comment: Ahmad: yes, and some sites(domains) can have only some plugins(partials) visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going through the this [series](http://codeofrob.com/category/10.aspx) of post by Rob Ashton specifically

1. http://codeofrob.com/archive/2009/11/01/dynamically-switching-between-master-pages-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx
2. http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/02/08/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc-views.aspx

However, I think though that you may need to do some overriding of how view names are resolved. The key point I think as noted in Rob's post is that views should be resolved and located in reverse order i.e. always look for views defined for your current site and traverse back to the root where a complete set of views are present.

> set of views per unique domain + one
>   default?

Yes - bearing in mind that you may only need specific views for a domain

> use areas?

No - i dont suggest splitting your app up using Areas in this case. I am assuming that you mean an area per domain. You should still split your app into Areas based on functionality and use the same idea resolving the views.

> any other idea?

Using Rob's idea is definitely a good option. I would however take into consideration how many  domains(sites) you are expecting to have different view for. I am thinking of the case (not very YAGNI) where every area for each site has different view requirements. So i a well thought plan is needed to stored the views. An example of a possible directory structure.

```
-- Default
   -- Area1  // Site2's views rendered from here
      --Views
      --Shared
   -- Area2  
      --Views
      --Shared
   ...
-- Site 1 // all views from Site 1 are rendered from this folder
   -- Area1  
      --Views
      --Shared
   -- Area2  
      --Views
      --Shared
-- Site 2 // only view for Area2 are rendered from here
   -- Area2  
      --Views
      --Shared
```

Comment: That's nearly the same what i was thinking about last night. I like this approach. One base set of views(masters, partials + css) and only distinct parts for specific domain. The custom view engine should resolve views from domain name. Thank You.

Comment: Glad this idea help. Would you mind updating regarding your progress and any issues you encounter (is this even allowed?)